# How to determine of an SQL table row contains values other than NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the problem:

I have a table with unknown number of columns. all the columns are real.

Assuming there is only one row in that table, I need a method to determine if there is a value other than NULL in that table/row.

I don't know the number of columns nor their name at run-time (and don't want to use c cursor)

SQL Server 2005

I appreciate your help.

Comment: "I have a table with unknown number of columns." - there's your problem!  Tables are supposed to have a known number of columns... Sounds like an abuse of Normal Form...

Comment: without column name how do you define condition u must use loop or cursor in this.

Comment: -1: "I don't know the number of columns nor their name at run-time".  False.  You do know this from looking at the table definition.  Don't try to write an magical piece of software that works under these impossible conditions.

Comment: This is a temporary table built in memory and part of a very big procedure. I agree that the solution is far form being perfect but it is finding a small patch or redesigning the whole query.

Comment: @Gilad: Redesign the whole query, please.

Comment: @Gilad: if you built the table in memory as part of a procedure, then the procedure will have the information necessary to determine the number and names of the table's columns. Amend the procedure accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way - CHECKSUM() returns no value if all values in the row are NULL:

```
create table #t (col1 real, col2 real, col3 real)
select checksum(*) from #t
if @@rowcount = 0
    print 'All values are NULL'
else
    print 'Non-NULL value(s) found'
drop table #t
```

On the other hand, I don't really know if this is what you're doing: a "temporary table built in memory" sounds like something you're managing yourself. With more information about what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to suggest a better solution.

And by the way, there is nothing wrong with a single-row table for storing settings. It has the big advantage that each setting has a separate data type, can have CHECK constraints etc.

Comment: Thanks, It seems that if there is a row of nulls there is a checksum value. In your example there are no rows at all so the return value is empty but you gave me a good idea on how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're doing some kind of a settings/properties table, based on the fact that you know you only have 1 row in it. This is the wrong way to do it, if you need to have dynamic properties; instead have a table with 2 columns: `option` and `value`. Then for each dynamic property, you'll store one row.

Comment: I agree that this is a better approach but the problem is that the problem is part of a much larger procedure and it is finding a patch or redesigning the whole procedure which might take allot of time.